# Get HTTP_REFERRER from Plug.Conn

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I developed a pixel tracking microservice using Elixir and Phoenix. I am trying to get the original URL where the pixel tracking is installed from `Plug.Conn`.

I assumed that I could try and get the Plug.Conn's `HTTP_REFERRER` header or variable or something but I must be wrong in maybe how the browser and HTTP works as I could not find anything about referrer in `Plug.Conn` in my controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The referer is present in `conn.req_headers`. You can get it using `List.keyfind/4`:

```ex
case List.keyfind(conn.req_headers, "referer", 0) do
  {"referer", referer} ->
    IO.puts referer
  nil ->
    IO.puts "no referer"
end
```

Comment: More tersely: `List.keyfind(conn.req_headers, "referer", 0, {"", "no referer"}) |> elem(1)`

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`get_req_header/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#get_req_header/2). For example

```
get_req_header(conn, "referer")
```